# android and ffmped. decode and play audio and video

Tags: android, audio, video, android-ndk, ffmpeg

I have compiled ffmpeg for android. Now I am able to decode vide frames with the help of ffmeg and then show them on a surfaceview in android using ndk. I have read a lot of tutorials and all of them explain how to play decoded streams with the help of Sdl. I have a lot of problems while compiling SDL so I want to ask can we play decoded audio stream without sdl, may be we should return decoded audio packages back to Java and then play them with the help of audiotrack class? Can you give me some advices? Thank you.

Comment: You can use built-in OpenSL for decoded audio. There are quite a few good tutorials available.